# Google plus appears like google signing in button android

Tags: android, google-plus, google-plus-signin

I have a project that i like to use login by google plus.
As in Google guides "created in console and open google plus api "
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating

Like shown here

```
<com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_signup_gmail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            />
```

And added also in my login class

```
SignInButton signInButton = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_signup_gmail);
    signInButton.setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_WIDE);
    signInButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            signIn();
        }
    });

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(Plus.API)
            .addScope(new Scope (Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN))
            .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.PLUS_ME))
            .build();
```

The problem is  that the button of google plus shows like this
 [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following instead:

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestScopes(new Scope(Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN))                
                .requestEmail()
                .build();
```

Then,

```
SignInButton signInButton = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
signInButton.setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_STANDARD);
signInButton.setScopes(gso.getScopeArray());
```

Comment: Thanks :) i took all day to do that

Comment: Glad it could help :)

Comment: can u please add the link that u got that from?

Comment: You can read the comment from line 67 to 78 at the following https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/android/signin/app/src/main/java/com/google/samples/quickstart/signin/SignInActivity.java